# Count amount of online users with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

I'm trying to count how many users are online on my site within 10 minutes and display it, but I'm facing some problems with my code.

```
//Count online users
//Data on DB: 2016-06-08 03:15:21

    $onlinesql = $odb -> prepare("SELECT `users`.`lastactivity`  count(*) FROM `users` WHERE `lastactivity` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE");
    $onlinesql -> execute(array(":id" => `lastactivity`));
    $rowonline = $onlinesql -> fetch(); 

    echo $rowonline;
```

It's not returning the number of online users, how can I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `users` WHERE `lastactivity` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

No need to use count(`id`) or count(`lastactivity`), just use count(*), because this is the fastest way

Comment: Ow, sorry. 
`SELECT count(*) as count`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to revisit your SQL. Here's an Example:

```
    <?php    
        $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(U.*) FROM `users` U WHERE u.lastactivity >= DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)";
        $onlineSQL  = $odb ->prepare($sql);
        $onlineSQL  -> execute();
        $numOnline  = $onlineSQL->fetch();

        var_dump($numOnline);
```

Comment: Didn't work, i got: `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/central/index.php on line 121`

Comment: @Joy Cooper    Sure... because $numOnline is an Array and we were trying to echo back an Array. Changed it now to var_dump(). Try it and see what you get.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax.
create an enum field in users table lets call it (status) 
'0'=> offline and
'1'=> online
and make two setInterval functions one to update user status each 2 minutes for example with ajax and another one to get count of users with status '1' from database with ajax too.